# I'm having trouble triggering a build from a Git tag

Tags: azure-devops

I want to trigger a build when any of the following is true:

- When there is a change to a particular branch (dev) **and** a subset of folders was modified (paths)
- When a git tag that matches a pattern (RC* or Release*) is set **and** a subset of folders was modified (paths)

When I add a *paths* statement to my yaml build template only my branch trigger fires. I am unable to trigger off of a tag. When I remove the *paths* statement both my branch and tag filters work.

What am I missing?

This triggers on branch = dev or tag is either RC* or Release*

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - dev
  tags:
    include:
      - RC*
      - Release*
```

This triggers on branch = dev only.

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - dev
  tags:
    include:
      - RC*
      - Release*
  paths:
    include:
      - /site/
```

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce your issue here. This issue has been confirmed as a bug and move to the product team . Please follow up this [case](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/671682/build-triggers-from-git-tag-are-no-longer-working.html?childToView=693978#comment-693978) and you can vote it to increase the priority. Sorry for this inconvenience.

Below is my reproduce:

[image]

When I added the paths trigger to the yaml, I committed the READ.md file and added the tag to the commit. However, it does not fire tag trigger. After I removing the paths trigger, the tag trigger will be fire normally.

Comment: Thanks for your response Hugh. Is there a workaround that you may know of?

Comment: If you need path filters as well as git tag triggers in the yaml file together,as far as I know,there is currently no workaround .This issue has been reported to product group for further investigation.After the product group fixes it, this will return to normal. It may take some time, please be patient to get their feedback later.

Comment: @yozepi This issue has been resolved and a fix will be rolling out within the next few days.
When a new tag is pushed or a tag is updated, we will ignore path filters and start a build if the tag matches the tag filter.